# Incorrect url matching for deep nested lazy loaded modules

Tags: angular, angular-routing

I have a large angular 1.x application which I am converting to angular 5 (via full rewrite) and have issues with route matching for nested lazy loaded feature modules.

The app is composed of several feature modules each with their own routing module and several of these modules are nested 3 levels deep from a routing perspective.

The route configs for each module are shown below with each config being included in their respective feature module using the Router.forChild() with the exception of the route level appRoutes which is uses outerModule.forRoot().

```
const appRoutes: Routes = [
    {
        path: 'dms',
        loadChildren: 'app/dms/dms-core.module#DMSCoreModule'
    },
    {
        path: '',
        redirectTo: 'dms',
        pathMatch: 'full'
    }
];

const dmsRoutes: Routes = [
    {
        path: '',
        component: DMSCoreComponent,
        canActivate: [AuthGuard],
        children: [
            {
                path: 'account',
                loadChildren: 'app/account/account.module#AccountModule'
            },
            {
                path: 'contacts',
                loadChildren: 'app/contacts/contact.module#ContactModule'
            },
            {
                path: 'projects',
                loadChildren: 'app/projects/project.module#ProjectModule'
            }
        ]
    }
]

const projectRoutes: Routes = [
    {
        path: '',
        component: ProjectComponent,
        children: [
            {
                path: '',
                component: ProjectListComponent
            },
            {
                path: ':id/correspondence',
                loadChildren: 'app/correspondence/correspondence.module#CorrespondenceModule'
            }
        ]
    }
];

export const correspondenceRoutes: Routes = [
    {
        path: '',
        component: CorrespondenceListComponent,
    },
    {
        path: 'search',
        component: CorrespondenceSearchComponent
    },
    {
        path: ':id',
        component: CorrespondenceDetailComponent
    }
]
```

This gives me routes such as:

- dms/projects
- dms/projects/search
- dms/projects/:projectID/correspondence
- dms/projects/:projectID/correspondence/:id

The problem is if I go to the url `dms/projects` it shows the content for `dms/projects/:projectID/correspondence` (which is also shown correctly by directly going to this path).

If I get rid of the `CorrespondenceListComponent` path in correspondenceRoutes the ProjectListComponent is shown correctly for the route `dms/projects`.

How do I get the intended route to show and prevent the router from falling through to the furthest leaf on the navigation tree?